# Construct a string path in cloud formation from existing resource

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm creating a managed policy in a cloud formation template which locks down access to an s3 container and key path. I've followed the docs in aws for using !Join but I am getting a malformed template error.

```
   Resource:
     - !GetAtt ACHSFTPProxyBucket.Arn
     -
     - !Join
         - - ''
           - !GetAtt SomeBucketICreated.Arn
           - /supersecret/upload/* #note I've also wrapped this in quotes and no dice
```

I've restricted access in the past using conditionals on the actions but was wondering if this could be done on a resource line and a !Join.

The output should look like this once deployed in the json editor of the console

```
Resource:[
   "arn:aws:s3:::bucketbname", 
   "arn:aws:s3:::bucketbname/supersecret/upload/*"
]
```

I've manually modified the json in the console to test if the policy works and it does just trying to figure out how to translate this to the template.

What is the correct way to construct the arn combinded with a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`Fn::Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html). Something along the lines:

```
   Resource:
     - !GetAtt ACHSFTPProxyBucket.Arn
     - !Sub '${SomeBucketICreated.Arn}/supersecret/upload/*'
```

Comment: That was it. One note in this format I don't need .Arn so
- !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${SomeBucketICreated}/supersecret/upload/*' is correct.

Comment: Ok, right. See the update - I think `${SomeBucketICreated.Arn}/supersecret/upload/*` is better than hardcoding S3 ARN prefix.